# Solr JVM is not getting updated

Tags: solr, jvm

Trying to increase the memory of Solr JVM in Linux

1. Added the changes solr.in.sh and solr.in.cmd both files
2. Restarted the solr service
3. Restarted the Server also
4. Tried to start solr with .\solr restart -p 8999 -m 1g , solr restart -m 1g

But no luck, please let me know if any other things needed.

Comment: What changes did you add? Where did you see how much memory Solr has available? What does the log show when you restart Solr?

Comment: set SOLR_JAVA_MEM=-Xms1024m -Xmx102m. Currently Solr has default 512 MB

Comment: Please edit your question to include WHAT changes you included in the mentioned files. Maybe there was a mistake.

Comment: try to start solr with `.\solr restart -p 8999 -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m`. Because `-m` is not the correct parameter to set the heap size.

Comment: thanks it is working.